# Video player with the option to see a small window in the corner

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-player

I am looking for a video player with the option to see a small window in the corner playing the video that I was watching (like in Skype).

Comment: can someone please answer me ?

Comment: So, you want to see the video playing normally, plus a second corner box showing the same video, right? Your goal is to keep having an eye on it even when switching momentarily to another application, I guess?

Comment: Hi Nicolas Raoul , yes this is exactly what I want